# One variable solver module in Python

Tags: python, scipy, equation, sympy, solver

I'm writing a code to solve for a root in a non-linear, one variable equation. The root has to be in the range of 0 to 1. The code I have so far works only with floats that have less than 5 decimal places, so I was wondering if anyone knows of a more precise solver module or function. (I've tried `scipy.optimize.brentq`, but I can't figure out how to use it.)

```
from sympy import Symbol, solve
def find_intersection(A, eV):
    x = Symbol('x')
    y = Symbol('y')
    y = (-(0.18*x + 5.87 - A)/(0.02*x-0.42))
    temp_x = solve(1.35-x+1.4*y-0.33*x*y-(0.758-0.28*x)*(y)*(1-y)-(0.101+0.109*y)*(x)*(1-x)-eV, x)
    for value in temp_x:
        if value>=0 and value<=1:
            perm_x=value
    return perm_x
```

Comment: The particular=True flag is supposed to give increased precision for solve, see http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html

Comment: Thanks for the response!
I tried the particular=True and it didn't seem to help any. The solver already returns very precise roots. I hope to be able to input more precise "x" values

Comment: Have you tried sympy.solvers.nsolve which is for nonlinear equations? Also possible is scipy.optimize.fsolve, see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html and section 5.6 of tutorial at http://www.tau.ac.il/~kineret/amit/scipy_tutorial/

Comment: The scipy worked great. Thank you.